# Difference between calling a Closure in Class via call_user_func and ::call

Tags: php, closures

I got a small Router Class that should return a user defined Callable or Closure. The Closure is saved inside a protected array with some additional information about the route.

This are (the important parts) of my structure:

**index.php**

```php
<?php 
// ... defining stuff

$router = new Router($_SERVER);

$router->add('/', 'GET', function() {
  //... do sth
});

$router->run();
```

**router.php**

```php
<?php
// defining....

class Router {
  protected $container;
  protected $requestUri;
  protected $requedtMethod;
  protected $routes = [];

  /**
   * Constructor will be responsible for parsing the 
   * request and create DiContainer.
   *
   * @param array $request
   */
  public function __construct(array $request, DiContainer $container = null) {
      // do stuff...
  }

  /**
   * Add route with callback to $routes array.
   *
   * @param string $uri
   * @param string $type Type of http request. Defaults to 'GET'
   * @param Callable $fn
   */
  public function add(string $uri, string $type = 'GET', \Closure $fn) {
    $this->routes[$uri] = [
      'type' => $type,
      'cb' => $fn
    ];
  }

  /**
   * Check if requested route exists in our routes array
   *
   * @param string $uri
   * @return boolean
   */
  protected function hasRoute(string $uri): bool {
    return array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes);
  }

  /**
   * Run the router.
   * 
   */
  public function run() {
    if (!$this->hasRoute($this->requestUri)) {
      header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
      return 'Route not found';
    }

    // Version 1. Doesn't work
    return call_user_func($this->routes[$this->requestUri]['cb']->bindTo($this)); 

    // Version 2. Works
    return $this->routes[$this->requestUri]['cb']->call($this);
  }
}
```

I just try to understand, whats the differences between `call_user_func` with the closure bind to the object and the Closure::call($this).

Version 1 with call_user_func throws the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property \Router::$container
```

But why is this working with Version 2? I tried to read the docs through both and in my head this should work the same way, but Version 1 doesn't seem to have access to `$this`. But why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php#refsect1-closure.bindto-parameters

`bindTo` accepts 2 parameters:

1. the object to bind to
2. the *newScope* to apply to that object. If you don't supply the 2nd argument then the default, *static* scope, is applied. If you pass through a string (the class name) or an object and then your closure will be scoped to that object.

> The class scope to which associate the closure is to be associated, or
>   'static' to keep the current one. If an object is given, the type of
>   the object will be used instead. This determines the visibility of
>   protected and private methods of the bound object. It is not allowed
>   to pass (an object of) an internal class as this parameter.

```
<?php
...

// Pass an object through as 2nd argument.
return call_user_func($this->routes[$this->requestUri]['cb']->bindTo($this, $this)); 

// Pass the class name (string) through as 2nd argument. 
return call_user_func($this->routes[$this->requestUri]['cb']->bindTo($this, 'Router'));
```

Comment: Thank you @waterloomatt! Need to learn to read the damn Docs. Doesn't saw that the second parameter defaults to static... thank you very much!
Just for interest: Using the `$closure->call($this, [params])` looks a little bit more easer to read and write for me. Any downsides of using that approach? Thank you!

Comment: I agree with you that `$closure->call($this, [params])` is more compact and easier to read. I don't think it was available before PHP 7 though. Go with that if you prefer it.